# Need Excel Forumla To Sort 2 Columns Which Both Contain Array Formulas

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting, excel-formula

I have created an excel spreadsheet to keep track of the >400 different types of beer that I have tried along with their home brewery, alcohol content, & rating. I have used array formulas to calculate how many different breweries and how many beers from each brewery as well as how many different styles and how many of each style I have tried. The problem I am running into is sorting the data. I have a list of all the various breweries (excluding duplicates) in column K. In column L I have the # of different beers I have tried from each brewery. I would like to sort columns K & L from most largest to smallest using the values in column L. Same thing applies for columns M & N except it's the styles not the breweries I'm tracking. I can't figure out how to do it since I'm using two array formulas, one in each column, and basically the results are conditioned on the results of the other. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Below is a link so you can download the spreadsheet to better understand what I'm doing.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cysa2rvcgcbs13c/TGS.xlsx?dl=0

Also the array formulas I'm using to make the unique lists in columns K and M are my first try at array formulas. Therefore, if someone could tell me if they are efficient or not and if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do which is look through the data in column B, discard the duplicates, and extract the unique breweries into column K. Same thing applies the styles in columns C & M.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All of your array formulas are doubled-up for error control. If you have Excel 2007 or later, you can halve the processing using `IFERROR` in place of `IF(ISNA())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is marginally possible to perform all counting and ranking within a single formula, the use of *Helper* columns makes much more sense and reduces calculation load substantially. For all intents and purposes, your existing unique lists and `COUNTIFS` are what the helper columns would contain and then you can return the values to another column based on the ranking of the `COUNTIF` returns.

[image: Brewer Ranking]

I modified your *array formula* from K2 and put it into P2 as,

```
=IF(LEN(P1), IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$501, MATCH(0, IF(LEN($B$2:$B$501), COUNTIF(P$1:P1, $B$2:$B$501&""), 1), 0)), ""), "")
```

The *standard* formula in Q2 was similar to the one previously in L2 as,

```
=IF(LEN(P2),COUNTIF($B$2:$B$501,P2), "")
```

The formula in L2 could now return a ranked result from column Q with this *standard* formula,

```
=IFERROR(LARGE($Q$2:$Q$501, ROW(1:1)), "")
```

With the ranked return in L2, K2 could return a matching brewery from column P with this *array* formula,

```
=IF(LEN(L2),INDEX($P$2:$P$501,SMALL(IF($Q$2:$Q$501=L2,ROW($1:$500)), COUNTIF(L$2:L2, L2))),"")
```

Columns S, T, M and N were similarly modified. Then everything was filled down to row 501.

I've made the modified workbook available on my SkyDrive [here](http://1drv.ms/1AHFcOG) for you to reference and download. Let me know if you want it removed.

[TGS (Jeeped).xlsx](http://1drv.ms/1AHFcOG)

More information on this method from [Multiple Ranked Returns from INDEX(…) with Duplicate Values](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2010-excel/multiple-ranked-returns-from-index-with-duplicate/0f258553-fd5f-47bb-99f1-ec72dc4e6135)

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for the help! I had read about using helper cells but hadn't been able to use them to figure it out just yet. You can keep the list or get rid of it. Either way is fine by me.